# Why are some points on my R plot bolded?

Tags: r, plot

Simple question. I'm plotting Home Games Played vs. Home Goals for some NHL Hockey data in R. Some points appear bolder than others, yes? Why is this?

Code used was simply:

```
plot(nhl$hGP,nhl$hG,pch=2)
```

Many thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Welcoem to SO.  Without seeing the data, we can't say for sure.  However, my guess would be that there are multiple values plotted on that same location: `plot(c(1,1,1,1,2), c(1,1,1,1,1), pch=2)`.

Comment: Ahh this makes perfect sense. I have a screenshot but am having trouble including it with html! But yes, that should be the reason. Thanks so much Justin.

Now how might I vote your response at the correct answer?

Comment: if it's what Justin said, you can use `jitter`: `plot(c(1,1,1,1,2), jitter(c(1,1,1,1,1)), pch=2)` or something to see the points

Comment: If any of the answers address your issue, please mark the checkbox next to them so others can see that this question is answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the data, we can't say for sure.  However, my guess would be that there are multiple values plotted on that same location: `plot(c(1,1,1,1,2), c(1,1,1,1,1), pch=2)`.

If you want to see the overplotting, you can either use `jitter` or `alpha`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because the points are overlapping:

Try tweaking the alpha component of the color, so it gives you a better visualization.

```
plot(rnorm(10000), pch = 2, col = rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.4))
```